# Evaluating large expression with differential equations constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the following lagrangian for a system, with $\theta$ and $r$ being the system coordinates:

$L = 2m\dot{r}^2+\frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot\theta^2-gmr(3-\cos\theta)$

Which gives us the following differential system:

$ 4m\ddot r-mr\dot \theta^2+gm(3-\cos\theta) = 0 $

$ 2mr\dot \theta \dot r+mr^2\ddot \theta+gmr\sin\theta = 0$

And take the following function:

$ H = r^2 \dot \theta \left (\dot r \cos \frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{r\dot \theta}{2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \right) $

Now proof, with Maple (or any CAS like SymPy, etc), that

$ \frac{dH}{dt} = 0 $ (that quantity is related to Noether's Theorem)

What I did was to define $L(r, \theta)$, $H(r, \theta)$, and using eval with the expression above and the differential system equations, but it returns the same expression:

[Maple worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5KJe.png)

How can I evaluate that expression using the differential system obtained from the lagrangian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you obtain your H from your L.

Below the two DEs (Euler-Lagrange equations) agree with what you gave.

I construct `Hdef` using the Legendre transformation of L.

I pass a set containing the two DEs as the third argument to Maple's `simplify` command. This is sometimes called "simplify with side-relations". And so I'm directing Maple to simplify `diff(Hdef,t)` subject to those side-relations.

```
restart;

with(Physics,diff):

L := 2*m*diff(r(t),t)^2 + 1/2*m*r(t)^2*diff(theta(t),t)^2
     - g*m*r(t)*(3-cos(theta(t)));

                       2                           2                               
             / d      \    1       2 / d          \                                
    L := 2 m |--- r(t)|  + - m r(t)  |--- theta(t)|  - g m r(t) (3 - cos(theta(t)))
             \ dt     /    2         \ dt         /                                

Er := - diff(L,r(t)) + diff(diff(L, diff(r(t),t)),t) = 0;

                                2                                 /  2      \    
                  / d          \                                  | d       |    
    Er := -m r(t) |--- theta(t)|  + g m (3 - cos(theta(t))) + 4 m |---- r(t)| = 0
                  \ dt         /                                  |   2     |    
                                                                  \ dt      /    

ETh := - diff(L,theta(t)) + diff(diff(L,diff(theta(t),t)),t) = 0;

                                              / d          \ / d      \
     ETh := g m r(t) sin(theta(t)) + 2 m r(t) |--- theta(t)| |--- r(t)|
                                              \ dt         / \ dt     /

                  /  2          \    
                2 | d           |    
        + m r(t)  |---- theta(t)| = 0
                  |   2         |    
                  \ dt          /    

Hdef := diff(r(t),t)*diff(L, diff(r(t),t))
        + diff(theta(t),t)*diff(L, diff(theta(t),t))
        - L;

                               2                           2
                     / d      \    1       2 / d          \ 
         Hdef := 2 m |--- r(t)|  + - m r(t)  |--- theta(t)| 
                     \ dt     /    2         \ dt         / 

            + g m r(t) (3 - cos(theta(t)))

simplify( diff(Hdef,t), {Er, ETh} );

                                  0
```

Comment: Actually the H was given (maybe the example is just wrong, sorry about that), but the `simplify` command was exactly what I needed, thanks! (and I had a typo when writing 'sin' in the screenshot, but it still didn't worked)